# How to define a harmonic coordinates on data graph?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spectral-graph-theory, data-analysis

Suppose I knew the Ricci curvature at some point of the Manifold along several directions (the number of directions should be much more than the dimension of the manifold). Can I decompose the Ricci curvature into the ones along the directions composed of the ones in a harmonic coordinate system?

I do not have information of the manifold. The manifold is composed of the data points which I suppose on manifolds. So, I have no idea how to define the harmonic coordinates on each data point and its neighborhood.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. This, according to my understanding, will be better received if posted on stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Hopefully..  thx~